# How add pattern to middleware in connect?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I have url:
`/api/v1/users/`

and i want to use middleware for all resources which include this pattern in url:

example:

`/api/v1/users/blabla`
`/api/v1/users/admins/root/bingo`
etc

`app.use(???, function(req, res, next) {...})`

How can I do this? thx!

Comment: So did you try `app.use('/api/v1/users/', ...)`?

Comment: it works, thx (Problem was with my very big and legacy project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to match all URLs that has `/api/v1/users/` in the route like this:

**CHOICE 1**

When you have many routes you can use this approach for your middleware:

```
app.use("/api/v1/users*", function(req, res, next) {...}));
```

**CHOICE 2**

When you have few routes, say- 2 or 3 then this is also the way to achieve it:

```
app.use(["/api/v1/users/blabla", "/api/v1/users/admins/root/bingo"],
  function(req, res, next) {...}));
```

You can also just try with:

```
app.use('/api/v1/users/', function(req, res, next) {...}))
```

Hope it helps you now.

Comment: so, add pls `app.use("/api/v1/users/", function(req, res, next) {...})` to your answer, for my accept as resolve